# Getting JSON back from rails with respond_with

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a jquery ajax call that goes to the create action, and I need to get the response back as JSON to then do something with it on the page in the success ajax function, but for some reason with rails it keeps throwing a missing template error:

```
class MembersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def create
    @member = @group.members.build
    @member.user_id = params[:user_id]
    respond_with(@member) if @member.save
  end
end
```

Should I be rendering nothing at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `@member.save` fails, then the default rendering will take place, which means that rails will try to render `create.*.erb`, or `create.rjs`, etc. You probably want to do

```
def create
  @member = @group.members.build
  @member.user_id = params[:user_id]
  if @member.save
    respond_with(@member)
  else
    render :nothing => true
  end 
end
```

Comment: seems like you dont gain that much from using respond_with in that example... http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/8/10/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-default-restful-rendering describes respond_with as handling http status codes for you

Answer (score 7):

I believe you should be using

```
respond_with(@member)
```

Removing the conditional.

This will use an "Unprocessable Entity" for json requests with an invalid object.